# What is the best translation for the word timeline?

Tags: word-request

I tried to do a Google translation of the word "timeline" but it just came up with "timeline" again.

Please can somebody let me know what the ancient and/or modern Latin translation is for the concept of a timeline?

Comment: And now I'm curious about its translations in *modern* languages, some of which might suggest calques, particularly from languages where declension is important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Linea temporum* is simple and should serve for most situations. This literally means 'line of times', which has 'time' in the plural, rather than singular, to indicate that the times in question are connected by a single line.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to Tom Cotton's good suggestion, I offer *linea temporalis*, "time-related line" or "temporal line".
Latin uses more adjectives than some other languages, English included, so *linea temporalis* is indeed naturally translated to English as "time line" or "timeline".